# How do I store a Set<UUID> to core data?

Tags: swift, core-data

I need a multiselection and I like to follow the examples in Apple's documentation

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list

But how do I save the Set to a core data attribute? What type of attribute is needed?

Comment: Did you see the answer I posted below?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help. Unfortunately changing attribute type to "Transformable", my app doesn't run at all. Perhaps, there's an error somewhere in database, but on 30 Entities, I don't like to find it. :) So I followed the solution with converting to JSON string and back. Works great.

Comment: Did you change the Custom Class? You have to set that to make it work.

Comment: Yes, I did. I think there's an hidden mistake inside of one of my entities. As soon as I change the type to Tranform.. I get errors, that there's something wrong with my database.

Comment: I had another field today and I tried it your way. Works perfectly. Don't know, why it doesn't on the other Entity. Only thing I had to do additionally: add `NSSecureUnarchiveFromData` to Transformer-Field.

Comment: The only thing that may be an issue that I had in my code but didn’t specifically address was the initialization of the set. If the sert nil you have to give it an initial value before you can insert and remove. That applies to any optional collections/objects. Make sure it is not nil when you are going to use it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at that later for better improvements. Storing the set is the better solution. It has to work somehow. :)